# Live paint bucket goes beyond borders

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

[image]

As you can see from the picture, the paint bucket fills over lines and thus i cant colour over my outline

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It's difficult to see what's going on here. Can you enable your Control bar along the top by clicking *Window > Control* and take another screenshot? It currently looks like you are filling it with "no fill".

Comment: Before you apply a color, you must select a color in the swatches panel. In your picture, there is no swatch color selected.

Answer (score 1):

A guess: You have gaps which are invisible in screen resolution or you haven't selected the ignored lines to be a part of the live paint group. The visible nodes in your screenshot doesn't tell 100% surely which paths are selected, but I believe this is a gap problem.

Live paint bucket has Gap options. By setting gap detection ON you can close gaps, if that's your problem.

An example:

[image]

All parts (=a rectangle and a line segment) belong to the live paint group, but the paint bucket seems to ignore the line. Gap detection is off in Object > Live Paint > Gap Options. After turning the Gap Detection ON only the pointed area is to be filled:

[image]

It would work without gap detection if the line segment was drawn from a node to node by having snap to point ON.